# Decode unreadable data from teltonika devices in to HEX String in PHP

Tags: php, gps, tracker

Hi I am trying to develop a platform for Teltonika devices where they send the data and I need to parse it in the location coordinates. I have done the handshake stuff and te device is sending the data, but the data is not a HEX string, I need the HEX string for it in order to decode the data. The string I am receiving is:

```
   a  ÷0 ,FÄ«¿ä@ {   Ê€C% ÉÿüB/    a
ã¨ ,FÅ´¿äÚ v "  Ê€C% ÉÿüB/    a Ð  ,FÅê¿ä¼ w #  Ê€C%É
ÿüB/    a   ¼˜ ,FÅ¬¿ãÒ z #  Ê€C% ÉÿüB/    ß˜ 357454072967951
      a      ÷0 ,FÄ«¿ä@ {   Ê€C% ÉÿüB/    a   ã¨ ,FÅ´¿äÚ v " 
 Ê€C% ÉÿüB/    a   Ð  ,FÅê¿ä¼ w #  Ê€C%ÉÿüB/    a
¼˜ ,FÅ¬¿ãÒ z #  Ê€C% ÉÿüB/    ß˜
```

But I need a proper hex string in order to parse the data in location coordinates. Can it be done in PHP and what will be the method to do it. ANy help would be of great help.

Comment: You need to make an attempt in code - share your code and explain where you are having trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert binary data to hexadecimal string, you could use [`bin2hex()`](http://php.net/bin2hex).